# Check if a drive is mapped and active

Tags: vbscript, mapped-drive

I have a requirement within my VBScript to ensure that a drive is mapped and contactable.

Initially I was using only the `DriveExists()` method of the `FileSystemObject`, but this fell short as in certain scenarios users start the day in the office but then take their laptops on tour, without shutting down; thus the drive in question is still listed as mapped, but is not contactable.

To Address this I have created the below function, but it seems a bit dirty due to the use of `On Error Resume Next`.

So my question is this; is there a method that achieves my goal built in to VBS, or is my approach (or similar) the only way it can be done?

```
Function CheckDriveExists(drive)

    CheckDriveExists = false

    If FSO.DriveExists(drive) Then  ' A drive is mapped for the required 'drive'

        '** Create a file name for the test file *'
        Dim tfDate, tfName
        tfDate = Year(Now) & Month(Now) & Day(Now) & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now)
        tfName = "tstfile-" & tfDate & ".bucf"

        '** Try to create and then delete a file on the usrs backup drive *'
        On Error Resume Next
        FSO.CreateTextFile(drive & ":\" & tfName)
        FSO.DeleteFile(drive & ":\" & tfName)

        CheckDriveExists = (Err.Number = 0) ' Check to see if the file was created and deleted successfully
        Err.Clear                           ' Clear any possible error              
        On Error GoTo 0                     ' Reset error handling

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: create text file imho not good way. perhaps you don't have enought permission to write, especially to root folder. sorry, no other suggestion from me. On Error Resumt Next is a good practic.

Comment: Good point about not having permission.  In this scenario it shouldn't be an issue, but worth noting for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from Windows Scripting documentation

```
Function ShowDriveList
   Dim fso, d, dc, s, n
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set dc = fso.Drives
   For Each d in dc
      n = ""
      s = s & d.DriveLetter & " - " 
      If d.DriveType = 3 Then
         n = d.ShareName
      ElseIf d.IsReady Then
         n = d.VolumeName
      Else
         n = "[Drive not ready]"
      End If
      s = s & n & "<BR>"
   Next
   ShowDriveList = s
End Function
```

perhaps you also need

```
Function ShowDriveType(drvpath)
   Dim fso, d, t
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set d = fso.GetDrive(drvpath)
   Select Case d.DriveType
      Case 0: t = "Unknown"
      Case 1: t = "Removable"
      Case 2: t = "Fixed"
      Case 3: t = "Network"
      Case 4: t = "CD-ROM"
      Case 5: t = "RAM Disk"
   End Select
   ShowDriveType = "Drive " & d.DriveLetter & ": - " & t
End Function
```